# Taylor series using OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

e<sup>x</sup> = 1 + x + x<sup>2</sup>/2! + x<sup>3</sup>/3! + x<sup>4</sup>/4! + x<sup>5</sup>/5! +...

I have converted a Taylor series of e<sup>x</sup> (above) into a program of OpenMp.
All the codes are written below.

When I run the code through Oracle Ubuntu it works.
It is giving me `e^0=1,e^1=2.718,e^2=7.389056`

But when I run it on Ubuntu (not virtually), then it doesn't work right.
It is giving me `e^0=nan,e^1=0.40..,e^2=4.780`.

And output is totally random as in its not exact as I mentioned above.
I need help.

```
 #include <math.h>
 #include <pthread.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 long double x, fact[150], pwr[150], s[1];
 int i, term;

 void *Power(void *temp) {
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < 150; k++) {
        pwr[k] = pow(x, k);
        //printf("%.2Lf\n", pwr[k]);
    }
    return pwr;
}

void *Fact(void *temp) {
    long double f;
    int j;
    fact[0] = 1.0;
    for (term = 1; term < 150; term++) {
        f = 1.0;
        for (j = term; j > 0; j--)
            f = f * j;
        fact[term] = f;
        //printf("%.2Lf\n", fact[term]);
    }
    return fact;
}

void *Exp(void *temp) {
    int t;
    s[0] = 0;
    for (t = 0; t < 150; t++)
        s[0] = s[0] + (pwr[t] / fact[t]);
    return s;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread3;
    long double **sum;
    printf("Exponential [PROMPT] Enter the value of x (between 0 to 100) (for calculating exp(x)):");
    scanf("%Lf", &x);
    printf("\nExponential [INFO] Threads creating.....\n");
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, Power, NULL); //calling power function
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, Fact, NULL); //calling factorial function
    printf("Exponential [INFO] Threads created\n");
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    printf("Exponential [INFO] Master thread and terminated threads are joining\n");
    printf("Exponential [INFO] Result collected in Master thread\n");
    pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, Exp, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3, sum);
    printf("\neXPONENTIAL [INFO] Value of exp(%.2Lf) is : %Lf\n\n", x, s[0]);
    exit(1);
}
```

The above code is originally for e<sup>x</sup> using threads which works.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    long double x, f, fact[150], pwr[150], s[1];
    int i, term, k, j, t;
    long double sum;

    printf("Exponential [PROMPT] Enter the value of x (between 0 to 100) (for calculating exp(x)):");
    scanf("%Lf", &x);
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(10)
    #pragma omp for
    for (k = 0; k < 150; k++) {
        for (int h = 0; h <= k; h++) {
            if (h == 0)
                x = 1;
            else
                pwr[k] = pow(x, k);
        }
    #pragma omp for
        for (term = 1; term < 150; term++) {
            f = 1.0;
            for (j = term; j > 0; j--)
                f = f * j;
            fact[term] = f;
        }
    #pragma omp for
        for (t = 0; t < 150; t++)
            s[0] = s[0] + (pwr[t] / fact[t]);

        printf("\neXPONENTIAL [INFO] Value of exp(%.2Lf) is : %Lf\n\n", x, s[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
```

And the code above is a conversion of the previous code to an OpenMP.

Comment: Post a [MCVE]. In particular, I'd like to know what inputs you have tried for which *any* system you run this on will give a correct result.

Comment: Your code has several problems. I do not understand why you reset your global `x` to 1 in your first loop. This will lead to incorrect results.  You have several globals that are updated incorrectly by the threads:  `f` and `s[0]`. For the second, you should use a reduction. For `f` use a thread local var.

Comment: There is a missing `}` before the second `#pragma omp for`

Comment: I'm intrigued to see so much effort spent in threading this code, which will not reduce its intrinsic complexity, where the terms could be computed incrementally at a linear cost instead of using a `pow` function and a nested loop.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `omp` to compute in parallel? The first 2 `for` loops can compute in separate threads, but the final `for` loop needs the results of the previous loops, hence cannot be started in parallel with the previous 2. It must first wait for both to complete.

Comment: Furthermore, you should compute the sum from the least significant value to the most significant value to minimize the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (t = 0; t < 150; t++)
            s[0] = s[0] + (pwr[t] / fact[t]);
```

This code, when parallelized, will overwrite the same variable concurrently with partial calculation results. This can only work when the threads are coordinated somehow. Fortunately, openmp has a dedicated directive `reduce` for calculating sums, so you can fix this easily.

In the `pthread` version of the code, one thread does this calculation, so no problem there.